# Formulate optimization problem and algorithm to divide region such that sum of distance is minimized

Tags: geometry, optimization, algorithms

Suppose we have $n$ points in a bounded region of the plane. The problem is to divide it in 4 regions **(with a horizontal and a vertical line)** such that the sum of *a metric* in each region is minimized.

The *metric* can be for example, the sum of the distances between the points in each region ; or any other measure about the spreadness of the points. See the figure below.

[image: Example]

I would like to formulate this problem, if possible, as a constrained optimization problem. Or how can I formulate it? Possible algorithms to solve it would also be welcomed.

Comment: Looks like, for example, you could apply two simple linear classifiers.  To get insight:  What would you do if you only needed to use one line, to break into 2 regions?

Comment: @Michael Yes, but the problem is that the points do not have labels (so we can't classify them)

Comment: I do not know what you mean by that. If you do not have $(x_i, y_i)$ coordinates for your points $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$, how then is the problem specified?  You would need such coordinates to compute your metric, anyway, unless you use the trivial metric all-zero.

Comment: @Michael I meant that each point with coordinate $(x_i,y_i)$ does not has a 0 or 1 as label, so that we can't classify them (as in a supervised learning fashion)

Comment: @michael the other problem is sequentially splitting could lead to a suboptimal solution when compared to jointly splitting.

Comment: You do not need such labels.  Suppose you make the problem easier and only look at the $x_i$ coordinates, and you want to choose a threshold $x$ to divide into two regions. How woudl you do it?

Comment: If there were $m$ points, a brute-force algorithm would require (at most) $m^2$ iterations, if $m$ is not too large, that might very well be good enough. To see this, create an ordered list of all the $x$ and $y$ coordinates. Then fix the $x$ threshold and iterate the $y$ threshold so that it moves between each pair of points in the list. Then increment the $x$ and so on. Since you are restricted to vertical and horizontal lines, this becomes a computationally feasible approach even for reasonable sized data sets.